# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

i was running some code and this error came after i hit the mole 2 times pls help me get a solution

what this basicly does is after i hit mole it gors anywhere randomely after i hit it 2 times this error comes to understand it more i have posted a video so u can see what is happening
link is https://youtu.be/Lga4SUVQtfc

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\whack a mole\main.py", line 74, in <module>
>    random = random.choice(random_locations)
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'choice'
> ```

code idk where the error is in the code so i am givin all the code

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import random

molepos1 = 0
molepos2 = 0


def mole_spawn_new(pos1, pos2):
    global final_pos
    final_pos = (pos1 + 67)
    global final_pos_2
    final_pos_2 = (pos2 - 3)
    global mole_rect
    mole_rect = mole.get_rect(center=(final_pos, final_pos_2))
    screen.blit(mole, mole_rect)
    return final_pos, final_pos_2


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption(' Whack a mole')
icon = pygame.image.load('whack-a-mole-icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# the screen
screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
background = pygame.image.load('green-grass-background-2036900.jpg').convert_alpha()

# everything releated to the mole with the mole of course
mole = pygame.image.load('small_mole.png')
mole_home = pygame.image.load('land.png')
mole_home = pygame.transform.scale(mole_home, (130, 80))
mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9)
mole_spawn2 = random.randint(1, 9)
while mole_spawn == mole_spawn2:
    mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9)
    mole_spawn2 = random.randint(1, 9)
if mole_spawn == 1:
    mole_spawn_new(100, 440)
elif mole_spawn == 2:
    mole_spawn_new(350, 440)
elif mole_spawn == 3:
    mole_spawn_new(600, 440)
elif mole_spawn == 4:
    mole_spawn_new(100, 260)
elif mole_spawn == 5:
    mole_spawn_new(350, 260)
elif mole_spawn == 6:
    mole_spawn_new(600, 260)
elif mole_spawn == 7:
    mole_spawn_new(100, 80)
elif mole_spawn == 8:
    mole_spawn_new(350, 80)
elif mole_spawn == 9:
    mole_spawn_new(600, 80)
# hammer
hammer = pygame.image.load('hammer.png')
hammer2 = pygame.image.load('hammer2.png')
hammer3 = pygame.image.load('hammer3.png')
whyamiahammer = hammer2

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if event.button == 1:
                whyamiahammer = hammer3
            if pygame.Rect.colliderect(hammer_rect, mole_rect):
                random_locations = [(100, 440), (350, 440), (600, 440), (100, 260), (350, 260), (600, 260), (100, 80),
                                    (350, 80), (600, 80)]
                random = random.choice(random_locations)
                print(random[0])
                print(random[1])
                mole_spawn_new(random[0],random[1])
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            whyamiahammer = hammer2
    hammerx, hammery = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    hammer_rect = hammer3.get_rect(center=(hammerx, hammery))

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (100, 440))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (350, 440))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (600, 440))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (100, 260))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (350, 260))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (600, 260))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (100, 80))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (350, 80))
    screen.blit(mole_home, (600, 80))
    screen.blit(mole, mole_rect)
    screen.blit(whyamiahammer, ((hammerx) - 61, (hammery - 73)))
    pygame.display.update()
```

i have tried to see what type of error this is and saw some answers but idk what to do so pls help me find out why this error is coming

Comment: You named the random location generated in line 74, "random" Refrain from using the name "random", which is the name of the module as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the name `random` for a variable, `random` is a module. Once you have a variable with the same name, you can no longer use the module because the variable will shadows the module. Change the name of the variable:

```py
location = random.choice(random_locations)
print(location[0])
print(location[1])
mole_spawn_new(location[0], location[1])
```